# Stream table rows are not clearing when I use procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created the task and procedure, and from the task I am validating whether the stream table have any new insertion then, I trigger the procedure from the task, but in this case my stream table is not cleared even, the transaction completed successfully from the procedure.

Could you please help me, how can I able to clear the stream when I execute the procedure from the task.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bizapp.service_site_arclight_vmtperiodic_procedure()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
VOLATILE
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
snowflake.execute({
  sqlText: "begin transaction"
});
try {
  const streamServiceSiteMappingQuery = `
            SELECT (column1, column2, column3)
            FROM <stream>
            INNER JOIN <table1>
            WHERE <condition>`;

  const streamServiceSiteData = snowflake.execute({
    sqlText: streamServiceSiteMappingQuery
  });

  calculated_column = <did some calculation with column>
  const insertQuery = `
              INSERT INTO <table2> (
                  <column1>,
                  <column2>,
                  <column3>,
                  <calculated_column>) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4);`;                
  snowflake.execute({
    sqlText: insertQuery,
    binds: [column1, column2, column3, calculated_column]
  });
  }
  // Added dummy ip validation to clear the stream table rows
  snowflake.execute({sqlText: "commit"});
} catch (err) {
  resultArray.push("ERROR: " + err);
}
$$
```

The above example is my procedure, here I am doing the **insertQuery**, will that not help to clear the stream.

This is how I am calling the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK <my_task_name>
WAREHOUSE = &task_warehouse
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('<stream_name>')
AS
   CALL <procedure>();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What in your stored procedure is executing a DML statement against the stream?  Can you share that detail?  Also, is it possible that data is still being added to the underlying table while you are running the task?

Comment: @MikeWalton, Yes it is against the stream, I am using the JAVASCRIPT in my stored procedure and trying to select the new inserted row from stream then, I do some manipulation with the data and update to another table, and no data add into the underlaying table

Comment: @MikeWalton 
SELECT * FROM <stream_table> INNER JOIN <join_table>  WHERE <conditions>`;
I executed the query using by snowflake javascript engine from the procedure, and based on the above result doing manipulation and update to another table with the manipulated data

Comment: Please post more code in the question so we can reproduce

Comment: Your DML statement must include the actual stream.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, sorry for the delay , Above I updated the task in detail

Comment: [Mike Walton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12178980/mike-walton)  ^

Answer (score 2):

You can't just run a `select` on a stream to clear it. You need to run some DML using the stream as a source in order to clear it. [This part](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#table-versioning) of the documentation explains it pretty well:

> Querying a stream alone does not advance its offset, even within an explicit transaction; the stream contents must be consumed in a DML statement.

Here is an example:

```sql
-- Create a source table & stream
create or replace table source_table(id varchar,name string);
create or replace stream source_table_stream on table source_table;

-- Create a target table
create or replace table target_table(id varchar,name string);

-- Insert some data into the table. This data will show up in the stream
insert overwrite into source_table
values (1, 'Mohammed'),
       (2, 'Simon'),
       (2, 'Mike'),
       (2, 'Felipe')
;

-- See what is in the stream. This won't clear the stream.
select name, id from source_table_stream;
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- |ID|NAME          |METADATA$ACTION|METADATA$ISUPDATE|METADATA$ROW_ID                         |
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- |1 |Mohammed Yasin|INSERT         |false            |c0ef6686b54ba0efb4bd8ab1917b203111f0816a|
-- |1 |Simon Darr    |INSERT         |false            |5643b2645856dd78fc505bfc72abc80bdb108634|
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+

-- The data is still in the stream...
select name, id from source_table_stream;
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- |ID|NAME          |METADATA$ACTION|METADATA$ISUPDATE|METADATA$ROW_ID                         |
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- |1 |Mohammed Yasin|INSERT         |false            |c0ef6686b54ba0efb4bd8ab1917b203111f0816a|
-- |1 |Simon Darr    |INSERT         |false            |5643b2645856dd78fc505bfc72abc80bdb108634|
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+

-- Run some DML to insert from the stream into the target_Table.
-- This will clear the stream.
insert into target_table(id, name)
select id, name from source_table_stream;

-- Stream is now cleared:
select * from source_table_stream;
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- |ID|NAME          |METADATA$ACTION|METADATA$ISUPDATE|METADATA$ROW_ID                         |
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
-- +--+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
```